# Inserting variables in Yii2 to Database

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I am trying to insert `$product`, `$pric` and `$user` to database table `cart`. Following is the function that I have created in `SiteController.php`.

```
public function actionCartadd($id)
        {
                $product = Additem::find()
                        ->select('product')
                        ->where(['id' => $id])
                        ->one();
                $pric =  Additem::find()
                        ->select('price')
                        ->where(['id' => $id])
                        ->one();

                $user = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;


                $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();

                $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                        ->insert('cart', [
                        'product' => '$product',
                        'price' => '$pric',
                        'user' => '$user',
                        ])->execute();
                if ($result)
                         return $this->render('custstore');
        }
```

However, this end up in error. Can anyone suggest any fix

Comment: What error? Please show us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following code

```
$result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('cart', [
    'product' => $product->product, 
    'price' => $pric->price,
    'user' => $user
])->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this fragment:

```
'product' => '$product',
'price' => '$pric',
'user' => '$user',
```

Use double quotes in values or just variables without quotes

Also, better way to fetch product and price:

```
$productItem = Additem::findOne($id);
if ($productItem instanceof Additem) {
    $product = $productItem->product;
    $pric = $productItem->price;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to insert the contents to the database table and I am not trying to fetch it. Also marking the values using double quotes or without any quotes didn't work.

Comment: He meana you don't need to call two times the function find. you can get the Model as he write in the answer and get all properties of the Model. It's better.